# How do I evaluate a column in for loop?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to create an email notification tool that will be trigger with a UI interfase, now the code runs perfect, includes the right Email Body, the right Email subject, etc. However, I'm missing a part where IF there is nothing to notify that row can be excluded from the batch of emails, I tried to just remove the email addresses from the emails column but that causes the code to crash. I'm trying to evaluate if orders is blank.

Thanks!

```
function emailNotifications() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("TestingSheet");
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  var templateText = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Template").getRange(1, 1).getValue();
  
    for (var i = 2;i<=lr;i++){
      
       var emails = ss.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
       var regionName = ss.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
       var orders = ss.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
    
    var messageBody = templateText.replace("{region}",regionName).replace(" 
     {orders}",orders);
    var subjectLine = "Important: New FBA Orders for " + regionName + " Region";
    
    
    MailApp.sendEmail(emails, subjectLine, messageBody);
    
     
 }
   
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Added an if statement

```
function emailNotifications() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("TestingSheet");
  const lr = ss.getLastRow();
  const templateText = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Template").getRange(1, 1).getValue();
  for (let i = 2; i <= lr; i++) {
    let emails = ss.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
    let regionName = ss.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
    let orders = ss.getRange(i, 3).getValue();

    let messageBody = templateText.replace("{region}", regionName).replace("{orders}", orders);
    let subjectLine = "Important: New FBA Orders for " + regionName + " Region";
    if (email) {
      MailApp.sendEmail(emails, subjectLine, messageBody);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Cooper, works perfect! Is there any difference in terms of functionality using Const/Let instead of Var? I noticed you changed that.